# flow in the bubble phase of the Event

Tags: apache-flex

Just want to know regarding the bubble phase of the events with some exp.

Can we set the bubble property true or false in run time. Please tell me

Thanks iin Advace.

Answer (score 1):

You can sen `bubble` property in `Event` constructor:

```
var event:Event = new Event("myEventName", true); // bubbles = true
```

Changing `event.bubble` property at runtime will have no effect. To stop event propagation use:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

or if you don't want to invoke listeners even from the `currentTarget`,

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Comment: Was pleased to help. If question is closed, please mark my reply as correct ;)